# Forcing open url in new tab with JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a View in Razor that when you have one set ViewBag, I want to open a url to print a report. I'm using Jquery code below, however, is opening in a new window and I want to always force to open a new tab, regardless of user configuration.

```
if (@ViewBag.Imprimir != null)
{
    window.open('/Audiometria/Imprimir/' + @ViewBag.Imprimir, '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0');
}
```

Comment: Why would you do this? As a user, I absolutely hate when I get a new window or tab from simply left clicking on a link.

Comment: Good idea, after saving the item, put at the top to print the report

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that whether or not a window.open() opens up a new tab or window depends on the browser implementation and user settings, and you can't force opening in a new tab.

Based on your window.open() parameters, most browsers will decide to open it in a new window, which makes sense since you have provided parameters to turn off certain UI elements (toolbar, location, menu bar etc.) that are usually present by default for all tabs, and usually it is not possible to turn off those elements only for a single tab.

If you omit the third parameter from your example it **should** open properly in a new tab in most new browsers, since you opening a plain new page without any specific UI settings for the browser, so there is a bigger chance that the browser will open it in a new tab.

```
window.open('/Audiometria/Imprimir/' + @ViewBag.Imprimir, '_blank');
```